.NET Core : efficiency of using multiple HttpClientFactory instances
I am developing a simple ASP.NET Core Web API which redirects its calls to different APIs (heavy load).
All of the APIs I call have the same settings, just different URIs.
The code logic determines which API it should call, only one or all of them.
Should I create a HttpFactory for each API service I call:
services.AddHttpClient("Api1", c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https:/Api1_Url");});
...
services.AddHttpClient("Api9", c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https:/Api9_Url");});

and call
httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ApiX")....

OR
should I use one HttpClientFactory for all APIs?
services.AddHttpClient("Api0-9");

Send full request Uri for each request (which is easier to code).
As I see it, it would be more efficient to use just one. Or am I wrong?
Is there anyone to understand HttpClientFactory down to its basics?
I have tried both. Both work. It is a efficiency problem... If there is anyone that understands HttpClientFactory, please let me know.

If you're hosting this in the cloud perhaps check whether your cloud provider already invented this wheel (eg azure APIM) ?

ASP.NET Core Web API which redirects its calls to different APIs redirect means that you instructs the caller to issue request against a different URL. In the rest of the question you talk about something very different. Could you please clarify?

From a performance perspective, as long as you're using IHttpClientFactory rather than creating your own transient HttpClient instances, you should be in good shape. Having different instances for a few dozen different APIs won't significantly impact performance--we're talking maybe 1 millisecond of difference over the lifetime of your application. Do what makes your code easiest to maintain.
For most applications, what's easiest to maintain is to use the typed client approach, injecting HttpClient instances directly into the class that acts as a client for each API. That way, the dependency injection layer handles lifetimes for you.
If you use CreateClient() then you need to make sure you dispose the HttpClient instance, so that HttpMessageHandlers can be reused efficiently.

Using IHttpClientFactory, you can have multiple, differently configured clients for different use cases. However, be aware that the factory-created clients are intended to be short-lived, and once the client is created, the factory no longer has control over it.
The factory pools HttpMessageHandler instances, and, if its lifetime hasn't expired, a handler can be reused from the pool when the factory creates a new HttpClient instance. This reuse avoids any socket exhaustion issues.
If you desire the configurability that IHttpClientFactory provides, we recommend using the typed-client approach.
-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#pooled-connections

Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

It depends on your request rate if it's a high load (like >100 req/sec) then the best option is to use a single HttpClient instance with a configured PooledConnectionLifetime and not use the HttpClientFactory. So basically you can create a list of HttpClients and pick one of them per required url.
HttpClientFactory everytime creates a new HttpClient instance and is meant to be short-lived thus always better to dispose the created object:
using var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

// use the httpClient and will be disposed 

If the request rate is not that high then HttpClientFactory would be enough.
Reading this document is highly recommended: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#pooled-connections

I'm curious what your first sentence is based on. IHttpClientFactory addresses socket exhaustion issues by pooling HttpMessageHandler instances, so why would it struggle to support >100 requests per second?

@StriplingWarrior using Single httpclient instance also fix the socket exhaustion as mention in the document. Here in this scenario multiple HttpClientFactory means having multiple pool of HttpMesageHandler where multiple socket will be taken at the same time and releasing each socket will take around 4 mins (2 * TIME_WAIT). so maybe still working with HttpClientFactory but for high load request using Single httpClient is recommended.
